# How to configure the number of workspaces in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, configuration, workspaces

Just upgraded to 18.04, and only have 3x1 workspaces. I'd like to configure it to 3x3 which is my usual setup, but couldn't find anywhere how to do so.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried it from gnome tweaks and workspaces in it? `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`